# How to remap the AltGr key on wayland?

Tags: fedora, gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, xmodmap

I'm trying to have the "regular Alt" instead of the AltGr key, this is because it would be more easily to me work with emacs with that setting. I tried to change the keysym with xmodmap but it does not worked.
I use Fedora 35 with Gnome desktop and a UK international keyboard layout with dead keys.

Comment: Fedora 35 uses wayland, xmodmap only works on X11

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper

Comment: Perhaps Gnome Tweaks has enough control for you to assign the keys you want.